# The triangle of forces - Lami's rule

Tags: statics

[image]

Hello there, In this question, I have to draw the shape so that I can solve the problem. I looked at the answer book and did not understand how to draw it. Can someone help me? Note that the answer is yellow on the bottom right.

Comment: Since this is homework you need to show your work so we can see where you are stuck (and to prove that you're not just dumping your homework on us).

Comment: No, sorry, I am not dumbing down my homework. I already have the answer because I have the answer book, but even after looking at the answer book, I did not understand how the teacher answered and drew the solution in this way, For example, in the problem  the string is drawn horizontally. The problem states that the length of the rope is 30 centimeters and the length of AB is 18 centimeters. I don't even  understand how to draw it horizontally ( the length of the string is 30Cm and AB is 18Cm so hooow)

Comment: You are correct that a 30 cm string will not be taut between two points 18 cm apart. So draw a diagram of how you think it should be. Then draw the force vector on the weight and from there draw them on the strings. Hint: what will the vertical component of the weight be on each string?

Comment: Another hint. Pythagoras with integers. It's a one liner.

Comment: Yes yes I think I got this thank you, now I'll tell you what I've understood, Suppose AB is a horizontal line with a length of 18 centimeters, connected to its end by a string with a length of 30 centimeters. If you put a ring on the string, the string will descend due to the weight of the ring, forming a triangular shape with AB as its base. Assuming that C is the vertex of the triangle, both AC and BC will be equal to fifteen centimeters. By applying Lamy's law, I can calculate the forces involved. , Am I right?

Comment: I never heard of Lami or Lamy but your mental model is right and the rest is trigonometry.

Comment: No criticism of you but who told you to get that book? The grammar, punctuation & units are appalling! Commas & other punctuation marks should not have a space before the mark. Sentences begin with a capital letter and for a number of decades the accepted symbol for gram or grams is g not gm. Also, there is no period (.) after units. What does gm.wt mean, grams weight? Is it supposed to be a mass or a force? Who is recommending this rubbish to you?

Comment: @Fred Sorry, I understand why you hate that book because of the linguistic errors. In fact, I am from a non-English speaking country, and this is one of the best books we have. The book contains some errors that can be discovered by anyone who speaks English, but for me, it is one of the best books as it contains a lot of exercises and ideas, Also, I am in high school, so I was not able to find many books, as the number we have is limited, and this is one of the best books

Comment: @YoussefSoliman: I understand your unfortunate predicament. Despite the handicap of having to use such a book, I wish you success.